# remove decimal point in ascii float number without truncating or precision loss

Tags: c, floating-point, printf, string-formatting, decimal-point

I have a float number in ascii that represents a voltage eg. 5.625V, and I need to remove the decimal point. I do not wish to truncate the number OR loose precision I simply need the number as is without the decimal point.

The resulting number will be inserted into an ascii protocol with a field width of 5 digits in length that represents a voltage and the units is in mV (millivolts) vs V (Volts) as shown in the example above. The number needs to be shown as 5 ascii digits, no decimal notation.

Eg. 5.625V float number in ascii to 5625 mV decimal number in ascii..

Seems simple...but cannot work out an elegant way to do this.

Comment: Multiply the result by 10000 and send as integer would solve the issue I believe

Comment: `printf("%f V is %5d mV", voltage, voltage*1000);`

Comment: 'I have a float number in ascii that represents a voltage eg. 5.625V' - does that mean a C-style string with a null-terminator, ie. "5.625V"?  Your question seems to suggest that, but some comments/answers indicate that it's a 'real FP value in some format, eg. single or double.  Which is it?

Comment: @shark.....no value is shown for the second argument, output shows..
"3.968346 V is            0 mV"

Comment: @Shark, if `voltage` is float, then `voltage*1000` is also float.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie ouch, my bad. i overlooked... use "`%f V is %5f mV"` or "`%f V is %5.2f mV"`  @jp54l sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just convert the number of milliVolts without the fractional part:

```
char buffer[32];
float voltage = 5.625;

snprintf(buffer, sizeof buffer, "%.0f", voltage * 1000.);
```

If you want to pad to 5 characters with spaces, and you know the number of milliVolts fits in an `int` you could use:

```
snprintf(buffer, sizeof buffer, "%5d", (int)(voltage * 1000));
```

If you are supposed to pad to 5 characters with leading zeros, use this:

```
snprintf(buffer, sizeof buffer, "%05d", (int)(voltage * 1000));
```

If the `int` on your platform only has `16` bits, you should use a larger type to avoid undefined behavior when converting a `float` that exceeds `INT_MAX`.  `long long` is guaranteed to be at least 64 bits. Adjust the `printf` format specifier accordingly.

Note that conversion to `int` rounds toward `0` and invokes undefined behavior if the value is out of range for an `int`.  If you know your value is positive and within range, you can get better accuracy with `(int)(value * 1000 + 0.5)`

Comment: If it is 5 digits, then maybe you want to multiply by 10,000 instead. But the unit will be wrong, I see... :(

Comment: @lan: the number is expressed in milliVolts, padding with spaces seem preferable.

Comment: Yes, I just note that too. It just inherently doesn't match: 5 digit and x1000...

Comment: pad with a leading zero.

Comment: @Ian: It matches just fine as long as the range is up to 99.999V.

Comment: @chqrlie: Note that converting to `int` will truncate excess precision rather than rounding (eg an input value of 5.6259 would be truncated to 5625 using the `int` conversion, but printing `voltage * 1000` using `%5.0f` would give 5626 which is more accurate).

Comment: @caf: good point.  Conversion to `int` rounds toward `0` and invokes undefined behavior if the value is out of range for an `int`.

Comment: snprintf(buffer, sizeof buffer, "%.0f", voltage * 1000.);

Comment: thanks chqrlie, your first suggestion resulted in 3964.7 after printing buffer.
I then tried you second suggestion, however I used sprintf and it gave the correct output after printing buff
sprintf(buffer,"%5d", (int)(temp * 1000));
printf("voltage: %s", buffer);
3964

Comment: @jp54l: it should not produce `3964.7`, did you use `%.0f`?  You could also try `%5.0f` or `%05.0f`.

Comment: Using `(int) (x + 0.5)` to round a FP number has a number of cases that fail (in addtion to "out of range").  Best practice: to round a FP number use `round()`.

Answer (score 1):

The question suggested the input was an ASCII string, so I came up with this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

long s2mv(const char *s)
{
    long mv;
    char *end;
    int sign;

    while (isspace((unsigned char)*s)) {
        s++;
    }

    sign = (*s == '-') ? -1 : 1;
    if (*s == '-' || *s == '+') {
        s++;
    }

    mv = 1000 * strtol(s, &end, 10);
    s = end;
    if (*s++ == '.') {
        int place = 100;

        while (place && isdigit((unsigned char)*s)) {
            mv += place * (*s - '0');
            s++;
            place /= 10;
        }
    }
    return mv * sign;
}

int main(void)
{
    const char *tests[] = {
        "0", "12", "-12", "12.", "-12.", "12.345", "-12.345",
        "1.234", ".123", "0.123", "-0.123", "-.123"
    };
    long mv;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(tests) / sizeof(tests[0]); i++) {
        mv = s2mv(tests[i]);
        printf("s2mv(\"%s\") returned %ld\n", tests[i], mv);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
s2mv("0") returned 0
s2mv("12") returned 12000
s2mv("-12") returned -12000
s2mv("12.") returned 12000
s2mv("-12.") returned -12000
s2mv("12.345") returned 12345
s2mv("-12.345") returned -12345
s2mv("1.234") returned 1234
s2mv(".123") returned 123
s2mv("0.123") returned 123
s2mv("-0.123") returned -123
s2mv("-.123") returned -123
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct! no need for floating point operations at all. I removed the tests on `*s` because `isspace()` and `isdigit()` are guaranteed to return 0 for `'\0'`.

Comment: I guess both answers are useful, since the question mentions the milliVolt value will be inserted into a protocol as a 5 digit ASCII string.